# Why programmers doesn't use material conditional (implication)?

Tags: logic, implication

Logical negation (NOT), conjunction (AND), disjunction (OR) and exclusive disjunction (XOR) are very often used in every programming language. Why isn't the material implication (p → q) used so often?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the ubiquitous "if statement" represents material implication

```
if p then q
```

If p is true then q follows: p->q